# Extracting Strings Containing Spaces

Tags: r, string, grepl

I am trying to remove rows from a data frame in R that contain specific phrases in one of the columns. So far I have been successful using the following code to remove rows containing the word "date":

```
newdata <- mydata %>%
filter(!grepl(".*date.*", column_name))
```

However, this code does not work when I try to select multiple words that contain spaces in between. How could I extract rows containing "unknown year" as well as "date"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newdata <- mydata %>%
filter(!grepl(".*(date|unknown\\s+year).*", column_name))
```